# TimerManager with random recurTime

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

I want a random expiration time on **EACH** iteration.
This example will only randomize an expiration time between 5~15 seconds and use them forever.

```
var timer = qx.util.TimerManager.getInstance();
timer.start(function(userData, timerId)
    {
        this.debug("timer tick");
    },
    (Math.floor(Math.random()*11)*1000) + 5000,
    this,
    null,
    0
);
```

I also accept an pure JS solution if any.

http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.util.TimerManager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `recurTime` argument to TimerManager.start is a normal argument to a normal function, so it is evaluated only once when the function is called. It's not an expression that gets re-evaluated over and over again. That means you only get equidistant executions with TimerManager.

You probably have to code what you want by hand, e.g. using `qx.event.Timer.once` calculating the timeout anew with each invocation.

EDIT:

Here is a code snippet that might go in the right direction for you (this would work in the context of a qooxdoo class):

```
var that = this;
function doStuff(timeout) {
  // do the things here you want to do in every timeout
  // this example just logs the new calculated time offset
  that.debug(timeout);
}

function callBack() {
  // this just calls doStuff and handles a new time offset
  var timeout = (Math.floor(Math.random()*11)*1000) + 5000;
  doStuff(timeout);
  qx.event.Timer.once(callBack, that, timeout);
}

// fire off the first execution
qx.event.Timer.once(callBack, that, 5000);
```